# Very different getopts results with different shells

Tags: bash, shell, posix, zsh, dash-shell

I did some option parsing in a shell script meant to be insourced in `dash` and `bash`, and I got some weird results in `bash`, so I put the essence of the script in:

./getopts :

```
fn()
{
    local verbose opt
    while getopts "v" opt; do
        case "$opt" in v) verbose=1;; ?) return 1;; esac
    done; shift $((OPTIND - 1))
    echo -n "'$verbose' "
}
fn -v; fn -v; fn -v; printf '\n'
```

and ran this with different (`local`-supporting) shells:

```
for sh in bash dash posh zsh; do echo SH=$sh; $sh ./getopts; done
```

The results I got are:

```
SH=bash
'1' '' '' 
SH=dash
'1' '1' '1' 
SH=posh
'1' '' '1' 
SH=zsh
'1' '1' '1'
```

What are the reasons for these discrepancies? Is the problem with `bash` and `posh` or my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `OPTIND` back to `1` before the `getopts` loop, so it will start from the first argument.

In `bash`, `OPTIND` is initialized automatically only when the script starts, in `zsh` and `dash` it's initialized when entering a function, and restored to its old value when returning from the function. I'm not sure what `posh` does.

According to the `zsh` documentation, you can make it act similar to `bash` by setting the `POSIX_BUILTINS` option. From the name, I assume the `bash` behavior is consistent with POSIX requirements, and `zsh` and `dash` are conflicting.